# How to use rm to recursively remove all dirs starting with a prefix

Tags: android, shell, adb

How can I remove all dirs that start with a prefix, So I have something like this

- xyzdirblah
- xyzdir2
- xyzdir3
- xyzdir4
- ..more

want to do via adb shell , android

Comment: If there happens to be a *file* called xyzdirsomething, must it be spared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rm -rf xyzdir*
```

`rm` is the command to delete things.

`-r` means recursively delete directories.
`-f` means don't ask questions, and don't complain.
`-rf` means both of those things together.

`xyzdir*` expands to the names of files that start with "xyzdir" (including directory names, since in Unix-like systems -- including Android -- directories are really just a special kind of file.)

If there are nondirectory files with the same prefix, like "xyzdir.txt", which you *don't* want to remove, you have to be more careful:

```
for i in xyzdir*; do [ -d $i ] && rm -rf $i; done
```

This loops over every file-or-directory with a name starting with "xyzdir" (the `for i in` part), checks whether it is a directory (the `[ -d $i ]` part), and if so (the `&&` part), removes it recursively (the `rm -rf $i` part).

Comment: This would delete all files starting with xyzdir as well... (I know the OP does not state that there are files with this name or not)

Comment: Thanks, it worked, -r worked but not -rf may be rm in android contains small set of params

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correct command:

```
rm -r xyzdir*
```

Jonathan's answer won't work, because `adb` does not recognize the `-f` switch.

---

EDIT: I believe it is not really the point of the question, but if you want to spare files called `xyzdir*` then use Jonathan's command without `-f`:

```
for i in xyzdir*; do [ -d $i ] && rm -r $i; done
```